# Can't seem to fetch from GitHub repository in PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, github, pycharm

Fetch failed: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

When I tried to fetch on PyCharm from my GitHub repository, the above is the message I ended up getting. I was wondering how I could fix this.

Comment: Can you `git fetch` from the command line? I assume [tag:github-for-windows] means you are on a Windows system. Which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seems like an overkill way of handling the problem but I have fixed it myself by re-installing git on my machine. It seems to actually be the fix for this. Another thing you could do is try git-bash (Git for Windows app) in the future.